# Fortran behavior of a tiny program

Tags: fortran90, gfortran

I am new in fortran90 (30 minutes ago...) and I have this program:

```
program example1
    implicit none
    real (kind=8) :: x,y,z
    x = 3.d0
    y = 2.d-1
    z = x + y 
    print *, "y = ", y
    print *, "x = ", x
    print *, "z = ", z 
end program example1
```

but when i run it with:

```
gfortran example1.f90
./a.out
```

the output is:

```
y =   0.20000000000000001     
x =    3.0000000000000000     
z =    3.2000000000000002
```

why is not 3.2000000000000000 ???
What I am doing wrong? 
Why y has a 1 in last digit?? and why z has a 2 in the last digit??
Sorry if it is a dumb question, but I just dont understand what I am doing wrong...

Thanks!!

Comment: If you are a beginner, try not to use kind=8, but get the value using selected_real_kind() function. The exact value (8 in your case) is processor dependent. Otherwise your problem has been discussed here many times.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with your program. The issue has to do with `real`'s inability to represent decimals precisely, without an error. The problem is that numbers not composed of negative powers of `2` must be represented approximately. That's why there is a small error in the 16-th decimal place. For more information about representation of `real`s [take a look at the article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). This is [another great article on the same subject](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

If you replace `0.2` with `0.25`, the problem will go away, because `0.25` is `2 ^ -2`.

Comment: thanks! so, for tihs example is better to sue real (kind:4) ??

Comment: @Edwardo Switching to kind:4 is not going to change much. As far as I know, Fortran does not have a base-ten `real` type (say, along the lines of .NET's `decimal`) to the representation error of decimal fractions is not going to go away.

Comment: Fortran standard allows arbitrary radix for numbers, but normally compilers allow only base-2.

Comment: If general, kind: 4 will make matters slightly worse, because kind:4 has even less digits for the approximation than kind:8.